# How to stop alert dialog from appearing after every stipulated inactivity time regardless of login/logout status

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, session-timeout

I am having an issue is which the alert dialog keeps appearing after every 2 minutes; regardless of login/logout status.

If the user is logged in, the alert dialog will be displayed AFTER 2 MINUTES and the user will be logged out DUE TO INACTIVITY and the user will be redirected to login page(CORRECT FUNCTION) . However, the alert dialog is still displayed AFTER 2 MINUTES when the user is not logged in initially (INCORRECT FUNCTION).

Hence, how to ensure that AlertDialog does not show after the stipulated inactivity time when the user is not logged in?

Below are the relevant code snippets:

METHOD TO CHECK FOR INACTIVITY:

```
//METHOD USED FOR INACTIVITY LOGOUT
//EMPLOY THE HANDLER METHOD FOR OCCURANCE OF FUTURE FUNCTION: DISCONNECTHANDLER
public static class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    public static Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){ 
        }
    };  
}

private Runnable disconnectCallback= new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Get the Resume Time & get difference in Time for Logout
        long endTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i("RootActivity:Runnabe()","******endTime=******"+endTime);
        long diff = endTime - startTime;
        long secInt = (diff /1000); //conversion of milliseconds into seconds
        Log.i("RootActivity:onRun()","******sectInt=******"+secInt);
        if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){// SET EXIT SCREEN INTERVAL LOGOUT
        IdleLogout();
        }   
    }
};
```

METHOD FOR LOGOUT:

```
//LOGOUT METHOD & CLEARING OF SHARED PREFERENCE CREDENTIALS
public void IdleLogout(){
    Log.i("RootActivity:IdleLogout()","******APP LOGGEDOUT******");
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE);             
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.clear();     // CLEAR ALL FILEDS
    editor.commit();    // COMMIT CHANGES
    Log.i("RootActivity:IdleLogout()","******loginButton is set******");
    setloginButton();   // Change logout button to login
    RootActivity.alertDialog(RootActivity.this,getCustomIntent(RewardsActivity.class)).create().show();
}
```

METHOD TO CALL ALERT DIALOG:

```
static Builder alertDialog(final Activity act,final Intent yourintent){
    Log.i("RootActivity:alertDialog","******Session Logout Info******");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    alertDialog.setTitle("SESSION LOGOUT NOTICE");
    alertDialog.setMessage("You Have Been Logged Out Due To Inactivity." +
            "Please Login To Access Your Profile.");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    //SETTING OF OK BUTTON
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            act.startActivity(yourintent);//Return page to PROPERTYACTIVITY
            }
   }); return alertDialog;
}
```

METHOD TO CHECK IF USER IS LOGIN:

```
  public void checkLogin(){
//CONDITION TO CHECK IF USER IS LOGIN, IF TRUE, CALL METHOD IdleLogout()
    if(getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE).getString(
    getString(R.string.pref_password), "") != ""){
        IdleLogout();
    }return;
}
```

Comment: Before calling IdleLogout() from disconnectCallback check is there anything in SharedPreferences. `if(getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE).getString(getString(R.string.pref_password), "") == ""){IdleLogout(); }`

Comment: @Aniruddha what do you mean? The shared preferences is supposed to be the credentials of the users when they logged in

Comment: Check if credentials is present when you call `IdleLogout() from disconnectCallback`. If credentials are present then only call `IdleLogout()`, otherwise don't. If I understood your code properly then it will stop popping alert dialog

Comment: that is what I did under the checklogin method, it is to check if the credentials are present, if it is then perform logout, if not shouldnt perform logout

Comment: I'm asking you to do the same thing in `disconnectCallback` method.

Comment: @Aniruddha so you are saying that in the disconnet method, instead of just "secInt > Inactivity_Timeout)" change it to "(secInt > Inactivity_Timeout && getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE).getString(
     getString(R.string.pref_password), "") != """??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if credentials is present when you call `IdleLogout()` from `disconnectCallback`. If credentials are present then only call `IdleLogout()`, otherwise don't. If I understood your code properly then it will stop popping alert dialog

```
private Runnable disconnectCallback= new Runnable(){
    @Override 
    public void run(){ 
        //Get the Resume Time & get difference in Time for Logout 
        long endTime= System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        Log.i("RootActivity:Runnabe()","******endTime=******"+endTime); 
        long diff = endTime - startTime; 
        long secInt = (diff /1000); //conversion of milliseconds into seconds 
        Log.i("RootActivity:onRun()","******sectInt=******"+secInt); 
        if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){// SET EXIT SCREEN INTERVAL LOGOUT 
         if(getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE).getString(
        getString(R.string.pref_password), "") != ""){
            IdleLogout(); 
           } 
        }    
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

Keep a boolean value of `isLoggedIn`

Initially, declare it as

```
isLoggedIn = false;
```

While user is logged in successfully, you can make that value `true`.

Later, before showing alert dialog, check the boolean.

```
if(isLoggedIn){
    //show alert
}
else{
    //do nothing
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No. In your `checkLogin` only. Along with existing check, you can check this, too. @ErnestLee

Comment: @MysticMike okay, will give it a try. I would just like to check with you that instead of what you have suggested above. I could also do this instead: "if(getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE).getString(
    getString(R.string.pref_password), "") == "" && isLoggedIn == true)" after which it will perform the logout that will automatically the alert dialog. yeah?

Comment: Yes. You can do that @ErnestLee :)

Comment: And make sure to change `isLoggedIn` to `false` if user logs out using Logout button or due to inactivity @ErnestLee :)

Comment: It is still logging the user out=(..I have initialize isloggedin to be false. and set the conditions as stated above.

Comment: @ErnestLee have you changed isLoggedIn to true and false properly? Use: `System.out.println(String.valueOf(isLoggedIn));` just inside `checkLogin` function before if condition. So you can verify if its true or false.

Comment: Thanks mate!!I have got it to work, have realized what the issue is!!